# Regular Expression: back references

Tags: regex, sed, backreference

```
sed 's/^\(\h*\)\(.*\)$/\1<!-- \2 -->/' web.xml
```

I think that this should take this xml:

```
<a>
  <d>
    bla
  </d>
</a>
```

And turn it into:

```
<!-- <a> -->
  <!-- <d> -->
    <!-- bla -->
  <!-- </d> -->
<!-- </a> -->
```

But what is doing is this:

```
<!-- <a> -->
<!--   <d> -->
<!--     bla -->
<!--   </d> -->
<!-- </a> -->
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `[ \t]*` instead of `\h*`, like so:

```
sed 's/^\([ \t]*\)\(.*\)$/\1<!-- \2 -->/' web.xml
```

[Here](http://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html#Escapes)'s a list of sed's escape (meta) characters.

Comment: Huh, you are correct.  That worked.  Why wasn't \h working?  Is it not supported by sed?

Comment: Yes, sed's regular expression support is pretty basic. Most regex engines support the meta-character `\s` and the class `[:space:]` for white space.